# Can I use kernel 3.2 in Ubuntu 11.04? 

Tags: 11.04, kernel, ppa

My kernel is now 2.6.38-13 in Ubuntu 11.04.

If I want to use kernel 3.2 , do I need to compile some drivers(such as hdaps, ATI video card) freshly ?

Is there any PPA for kernel 3.2 in Ubuntu 11.04 ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you would need to compile your own kernel for 3.2 in 11.04.

There is a mainline kernel ppa here:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

But it looks as if they have packaged 3.2 for 11.10 and 12.04 (not 11.04).

Do you know how to compile a kernel ?
What make you want the 3.2 kernel ?

Comment: Kernel 3.2 improve ext4 file system and more energy saving .